# Apple Touch Icon - Are .ico files allowed?

Tags: html, png, ico

Seems like nobody has asked this question before or I just can't find it. Are .ico files allowed on Apple Touch?

Comment: This file should be a .png,

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html: "... place an icon file in PNG format ..." is pretty clear.